# Selenium test fails to log me in - can do it manually

Tags: .net, unit-testing, selenium, nunit

I have a Selenium feature file that basically goes like this:

```
Given I'm logged in as administrator
When I navigate to the create item page
And I fill out the form as follows
| Label           | Value              |
    // form data here
And I press save on the create item page
Then I am at the edit item page
And The form is filled out as follows
   // same form data here
```

To run this test, I first start an IIS Express instance from Visual Studio by hitting "run without debugging", and when that's up and running, I hit "run unit test" in the Unit Test Explorer.

The problem is, when I run this test from NUnit, for some reason the login step doesn't work - instead of getting to the start page of my web site, I get back to the login page with a `ReturnUrl` query string parameter of where I wanted to go. If I do exactly the same things manually (type in the same username and password for logging in, for example), the login is successful.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually loged before "When I navigate to the create item page" step?. Do have a wait after login step or do you check if you are at the main page before navigate?. Could you show your steps code?

Comment: @Morvader: That did in fact turn out to be the problem. If you write it as an answer I can give you rep for it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your not actually loged when *"When I navigate to the create item page*" step is executed.

Probably you should check firts if you are at the main page. You can do this using `wait` command, for example:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("main page");
            }
```

Hope help!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but in :

```
Given I'm logged in as administrator
```

is the entire logic for the login process (I also did it for [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)). So the key to your solution can very easy be - just to debug (trace the invocation tree) the `methods` responsible for/behind this binding. Also sometimes caching can be the root. I always clear it at the `@TestInitialize`